# Recyclerview showing data only first time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I am using firebase to retrieve some products. I have logged and the data does come through each time I click. But apparently the recyclerview only shows the data once.

Here is the link to a video showing the issue. [video link](https://mega.nz/#!cBonAICQ!Ol2i2kNQvfr7kZ_VNRJUAt6HHg-E8QQsliq_q2lfByQ)

**Setting up RecyclerView**

```
private void setupRecyclerView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupRecyclerView: setting up recyclerview");
    productList = new ArrayList<>();
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    this.adapter = new ProductListAdapter(productList);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Getting products from Firebase**

```
private void getProducts() {

    //Setting up Event Listener
    productsListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Product p = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: Adding Product = "+p.toString());

            //Pass Products to Proucts fragment
            addProduct(p);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged: child Product changed, snapshot="+dataSnapshot.toString());
            editProduct(dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    //Get Products from firebase
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user_photos").child(mFirebaseStoreID).addChildEventListener(productsListener);
}
```

**Add Product Method**

```
public void addProduct(Product newProduct) {
    double price=0;
    if (!newProduct.getAssociated_product_price().equals("")){
        price = Double.valueOf(newProduct.getAssociated_product_price());
    }
    productList.add(new ProductCard(newProduct.getAssociated_product_name(), newProduct.getAssociated_product_description(), newProduct.getImage_path(), price,newProduct.getPhoto_id()));
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(productList.size() - 1);
    Log.d(TAG, "addProduct: Product added total size= " + productList.size() + " and adapter size= " + adapter.getItemCount());
}
```

There is a lot of code, let me know if this isn't enough. The behavior is very strange though.

Comment: rv.setHasFixedSize(false); try this or remove the line completely

Comment: @ZaidMirza Check your `layout` which is used in adapter, does `root layout` has `height` set as  `match_parent` if does, change it to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `setupRecyclerView` method remove the line `rv.setHasFixedSize(false)`.

The [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setHasFixedSize(boolean)) for `setHasFixedSize` says:

> RecyclerView can perform several optimizations if it can know in
>   advance that RecyclerView's size is not affected by the adapter
>   contents. RecyclerView can still change its size based on other
>   factors (e.g. its parent's size) but this size calculation cannot
>   depend on the size of its children or contents of its adapter (except
>   the number of items in the adapter).
>
> If your use of RecyclerView falls into this category, set this to
>   true. It will allow RecyclerView to avoid invalidating the whole
>   layout when its adapter contents change.

Since your content from adapter is changing when you are notifying it for item inserted so you should not set it to `true`.